# passing number to function for loop with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameter-passing

I was wondering how to pass a number to a function I created for a loop. For example, I have a loop that simply adds 1 to a value when it runs. How would I go about passing how many times I want the loop to run in a function? Like so:

```
var i = 0;
function blahBlah (i ?){
for (i=0,i>10(this is what I want to pass to the function),i++){
i++;
}

Then call the function:

blahBlah(number of times I want it to run);
```

Comment: Can you provide more context for your question? I can't figure out what exactly you need to happen.

Comment: What would you do in ActionScript?

Comment: No worries, there are no noob questions, just strange answers. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function blahBlah (noOfTimes){
  for (var i=0 ;i < noOfTimes ;i++){
    //i++; you already incremented i in for loop
    console.log(i);//alert(i);
    }
  }

blahBlah(10);// call function with a loop that will iterate 10 times
```

Comment: :) uh... 1/3 cup left... If I see a funny answer I'll go to take a new one ;)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure i understand the question, but how about

```
function blahBlah(n) {
    for(var i=0; i < n; i++) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean calling the function each iteration?

```
function blahBlah( i ) {
    // do something with i
}

for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    blahBlah( i );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```
function runLoop(length) {
    for (var i=0; i < length; i++) {
        {loop actions}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you used , instead of ; in for loop.

Second, you need two variables here: the first one is how many times to repeat (`i`, the argument), the second is a counter (`a`, which iteration is it now)

```
function blah(i) {
    for (var a=0; a<i; a++) {
        doStuff();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop inside your function:

```
function BlahBlah(n) {
   for (i=0; i < n; ++i) {
      // do something...
   }
}
```

or simply invoke the function in a for loop:

```
function Blahblah() { /* do something */ }

// elsewhere:
n = 42;
for (i=0; i < n; ++i) BlahBlah();
```

Comment: in each version, you may use `n` itself as counter, like `while (n--) BlahBlah();`